# Can we say that $\frac{a+b}{c+d} \leq \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d} $

Tags: inequality

If $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers, can we say that $\frac{a+b}{c+d} \leq \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d} $ is always true? If no, can you please give insignts on under which conditions this might be true.

Any references to a similar type of inequalities are also welcome

Thank you,

Comment: You must add the assumption that b,c and d are all non-zero real numbers.

Comment: Did you want $\dfrac  ac+\dfrac bd$?

Comment: @NoChance Mmost positve numbers are nonzero

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks for pointing out my blunder!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution to new version:

Since $$\frac{a}{c+d}  \leq \frac{a}{c}$$
and
$$\frac{b}{c+d}  \leq \frac{b}{d}$$
we have
$$\frac{a+b}{c+d} = \frac{a}{c+d} + \frac{b}{c+d} \leq \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d} $$

Comment: Oh, so much easier if one does not show $\le\max\{\frac ac,\frac bd\}$ first :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to first version of the problem: Does following holds 
$${a+b\over c+d}\leq {a\over b}+{c\over d}$$

No, put $a=c= 1$ and $b=d=3$ and we get $${1+3\over 1+3}\nleq {1\over 3}+{1\over 3}$$

Comment: I think I found the problem.

Comment: @Botond: Sorry, My initial question was wrong! I have edited it now.

Comment: Your approach is wrong cause when $a=c=1$ and $b=d=3$ the inequality is: $\frac{1+3}{1+3} \le \frac{1}{1}+ \frac{3}{3}$ which holds.

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis That was an answer to previous verison of the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry! Is saw the edited one and I was confused. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

After the latest edit:

Wlog. $\frac ac\le\frac bd$. Then $$\frac ac\le\frac{a+b}{c+d}\le\frac bd<\frac ac+\frac bd$$

Indeed, $\frac ac\le \frac bd$ implies $\frac{bc-ad}{cd}\ge 0$, i.e., $bc-ad\ge 0$.
Then 
$$ \frac bd-\frac{a+b}{c+d}=\frac{b(c+d)-d(a+b)}{d(c+d)}=\frac{bc-ad}{d(c+d)}\ge0$$
and
$$ \frac{a+b}{c+d}-\frac ac=\frac{c(a+b)-a(c+d)}{(c+d)a}=\frac{bc-ad}{(c+d)a}
\ge 0$$

Comment: Sorry, My initial question was wrong! I have edited it now.